# VARCHAR variable not recognized when importing data into table pgADMIN

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I created a table using the following statement in pgAdmin4

```
create table web_data(
    timestamp TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE,
    device_type VARCHAR(50),
    session_id VARCHAR(100),
    customer_id VARCHAR(150),
    url VARCHAR(100),
    purchase_id VARCHAR(100)
    );
```

Resulting in the following table

[image]

When importing the CSV file an error 1 is returned stating that in column customer_id the timestamp is invalid, however no timestamp is given in this column. The full error is:

```
ERROR:  time zone "f3285a42f7199" not recognized
CONTEXT:  COPY web_data, line 2, column datum: "122048f3285a42f7199"
```

It seems as if 122048 is identified as a time stamp and f3285a42f7199 is identified as a time zone, when in fact this is just a long string identifying the customer.

How can I adjust the table so that I can insert my full table.

Comment: You  need to fix which columns in the data are mapped to which columns in the table.  Something is off.

Comment: Per @GordonLinoff you will need to make the order of the columns in the CSV file match those of the table. Either reorder in the CSV file or specify the column order in the `COPY` command itself, per [COPY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html). While you are at I would change the `timestamp` field name to something that does not match a type name. It will save you confusion later.